# Show Tooltip immediately after click

Tags: wpf, tooltip

I've got a `Tree` with custom `TreeViewItem`s. The `TreeViewItem`s contains a `CheckBox`. When I click on a `CheckBox` the background logic decides whether the click was valid or not and if it was invalid a warning message should be shown.

I added a `Tooltip` to each `TreeViewItem` and set the visibility to Collapsed when doing declaration. The `Tooltip` should show the message but if I set it to Visible in the TvItems click event it doesn't appears immediately just after it gets the mouseOver event again. Its the same if I set the `IsOpen` property in the event.

How can I force the Tooltip to appear when I want in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the [ToolTipService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltipservice.aspx) class to set the `InitialShowDelay` to 0. But i think this will also show the tooltip directly when you hover your mouse over the element.

Maybe you should reconsider this design, because i think what you want to do proves to be difficult in some circumstances or not usable.

If you want to do it on a mouse Click, i would use a [attached behavior](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AttachedBehaviors.aspx) to hook the mouse click, and show the tooltip by hand, which can be accomplished by grabbing the `ToolTip` of your `TreeViewItem` and setting `IsOpen` to true.